# dismiss UISearchController's searchResultsUpdater need press twice

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I have a search button when press to present a `ViewController` for search functions. This view controller contains a `UITableView` and `UISearchController`.

All works well but after i select one of the search results. I want to dismiss this view controller directly, but the first select dismiss the cancel then select again will dismiss the view controller. Like below, i just want to one select dismiss. Thanks!

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        searchViewController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    }
```

**EDIT**

```
let searchViewController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
func configureSearchController() {
        tableView.tableHeaderView     = searchViewController.searchBar
        searchViewController.delegate = self
        searchViewController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.definesPresentationContext = true
        searchViewController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    }
```

Comment: Do you pass a custom searchResultsController when you create your UISearchController ?

Comment: Pass to whom? See my edit. thanks.

Comment: Pass during the creation of your UISearchController, but you don't.

Answer (score 7):

The following two steps should do the trick you're looking for:

First, you need to cancel your search upon selection of a row like so:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    searchController.active = false
}
```

Second, you need to implement one of the delegate method of UISearchControllerDelegate in order to dismiss your view controller upon "cancellation" of your search:

```
extension SearchViewController: UISearchControllerDelegate {

func willDismissSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    print("Will dimiss search controller")
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Comment: thanks you do give me a hint, not necessary `dismissViewController` in delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to handle this issue is to ask *the presenting view controller to dismiss* as opposed to `self`.

This is expected behaviour. From [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss):

> The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view controller it presented. If you call this method on the presented view controller itself, UIKit asks the presenting view controller to handle the dismissal.

So what is happening to you is that you have:

Presenting View Controller (PVC) -> Presented View Controller (PVD) -> Search Results View Controller (SRVC)

When you call (the first time) `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated` from PVD what you are actually asking is for PVD to dismiss SRVC. Once SRVC is dismissed, calling `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated` again means UIKit asks the presenting view controller to handle the dismissal (as per the docs). Therefore requiring 2 taps to dismiss the current controller.

You could fix this by simply calling `dismiss` from PVC instead.